# Can't ping outside in VM created by Multipass

Tags: multipass

Using [multipass](https://multipass.run) created 3 VMs

```
$ multipass ls
Name                    State             IPv4             Image
node1                   Running           192.168.64.1     Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
node2                   Running           192.168.64.2     Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
node3                   Running           192.168.64.3     Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
```

Login to them can't run `curl`, `wget`. Can't ping `8.8.8.8`.

What's the reason?

Answer (score 0):

I also couldn't ping outsite on multipass and tried to solve this problem but couldn't solve it.

So I uninstalled multipass.

```
sudo snap remove multipass
```

Then I installed multipass again.

```
sudo snap install multipass
```

Finally I could ping outside.